# Получение одиночного символа из строки

Tags: rust

**Вопрос:** После исполнения кода я получаю `Some('H')`.   Как правильно получить одиночный символ строки?

**Код:**

```
fn main(){
    let strr="Hello";
    println!("{:?}",strr.chars().nth(0));
}
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc781ddb6e6d3441125a2f6a8d7162e6&version=stable

Comment: Еще добавить `.nth(0).unwrap()`?

Comment: Код примера не совпадает с заголовком вопроса: вы пытаетесь итерировать символы в строке и достать некоторый по счету.

Индексирование строк эффективно делается встроенными операторами индексирования по диапазону, но на выходе получаются отрезки строк и с индексами нужно быть осторожным, иначе можно "разрезать" кодовую последовательность UTF-8 и получить панику. См. также метод `char_indices()`.

Comment: Я с вами согласен " Индексирование строк эффективно делается встроенными операторами индексирования по диапазону,".  Он нашел самый ужасный метод получения индекса строки.   По коду это целый цикл...  fn nth(&mut self, mut n: usize) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        for x in self {
            if n == 0 { return Some(x) }
            n -= 1;
        }
        None
    }

Comment: Бо это Iter и без цикла получить определенную позицию Iter нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fn main(){
    let strr="Hello";
    println!("{:?}",strr.chars().nth(0));
}
```

*"После компиляции и запуска получаю Some('H').
Как получить (просто индекс без посторонних символов) H без Some()?"*

**Я вообще худею от таких вопросов. Информация:**

`Option` это аналог `null`, его безопасная версия. Тоесть если индекса `0` в строке не существует вернется `None`, а если индекс существует то там будет `Some('')`. Сам `Option` это `enum` имеющий или `Some` или  `None`.

Метод `Chars` `nth` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html

```
fn nth(&mut self, n: usize) -> Option<Self::Item>[src]  //ВОЗВРАТ OPTION

Returns the nth element of the iterator.
```

**Как обрабатывать Option??**

```
fn main() {
    let test_str = "Hello";

    let mut test_chars = test_str.chars();
    if let Some(a) = test_chars.nth(0) { //ЕСЛИ ФУНКЦИЯ ВЕРНУЛА OPTION::SOME(A) то
        println!("{:?}", a);
    }
    //НО НЕ ПРОВЕРЯЕТСЯ ЕСЛИ ИНДЕКСА 0 В СТРОКЕ НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ
}
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d543bbf77e8ad87976246753bedd69df&version=stable

```
fn main() {
    let test_str = "Hello";

    let mut test_chars = test_str.chars();
    match test_chars.nth(0) {
        Some(a) => {
            println!("{:?}", a);
        },
        None => {
            println!("Индекса 0 в строке test не существует. Спасибо за внимание.");
        }
    }
    //Этот пример мне нравится больше, в нем вы можете реагировать на отсутствие индекса, или на его присутствие. И намного лучше еслиб вы в прошлом примере писали else к if.
}
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=586bac28433d519d5771269441a351de&version=stable

**Плохой пример:**

```
fn main() {
    let test_str = "Hello";

    let mut test_chars = test_str.chars();

    let char_a = test_chars.nth(0).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", char_a);

}
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c87388771277e5337ded6d38c56fdee6&version=stable

*Лучше сами описывайте действия реакции на отсутствие индекса, чем используйте unwrap. Unwrap говорит если вернули Some(a) то запиши 'a' в переменную, а если индекса 0 не существует то прерви программу.*

**Совет:**
Не используйте метод `NTH` для таких целей как получить индекс строки. Сведи с тем что он работает для немного другой цели.

```
fn nth(&mut self, mut n: usize) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        for x in self {
            if n == 0 { return Some(x) }
            n -= 1;
        }
        None
    }
```

Для таких целей хорошо подойдет: (но он возвращяет именно str)

```
fn main() {
    let strr="Hello";
    if let Some(a) = strr.get(0..1){
        println!("{:?}", a);
    }
}
```

**Запуск:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc781ddb6e6d3441125a2f6a8d7162e6&version=stable

Answer (score 0):

Метод `nth()` типажа `Iterator` возвращает `Option`, потому что итерация, в общем случае, может закончиться до того, как указанный элемент будет достигнут. Если вы уверены, что значение есть, можно достать его из `Option` методами `unwrap()` или `expect()`:

```
fn main(){
    let strr = "Hello";
    let iter = strr.chars();
    let c = iter.nth(0).expect("leading character not present");
}
```